# Can an asteroid have a magnetic field?

Tags: astronomy, magnetic-fields, asteroids

Some M-type asteroids are [believed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_meteorite) to be metallic, even possessing Nickel-Iron.

Given

- the proximity of the asteroid belt to Jupiter's magnetosphere,
- the regularity of motion of any given M asteroid relative to Jupiter
- the ease with which Nickel/Iron may be magnetized, and
- the strength of Jupiter's magnetic field

Is it reasonable to expect an M-type asteroid that fulfills such conditions to exhibit a magnetic field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a general sense, yes, asteroids can have magnetic fields - for example, in the article ["Magnetic Field Signatures Near Galileo's closest approach to Gaspra"](http://www.igpp.ucla.edu/people/mkivelson/Publications/146-93Sci261331.pdf) (Kivelson et al. 1993), Gaspra, an S-type asteroid with an unusually metal and olivine abundance exhibited what has been suggested by the article as a measurable magnetic field.

In the article ["Observations of the Magnetic Fields Inside and Outside the
Solar System: From Meteorites (~ 10 attoparsecs),
Asteroids, Planets, Stars, Pulsars, Masers, To Protostellar
Cloudlets (< 1 parsec)"](http://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/March03/Vallee2/paper.pdf) (Vallee, 1998) (section 2.1.3 on page 6-7), further information is provided about the asteroid Gaspra and also mentions another S-type asteroid 243 Ida as having a measurable (likely to be remanent) magnetic field.

According to the article ["Possible evidence for partial differentiation of asteroid Lutetia from Rosetta"](http://scripts.mit.edu/~paleomag/articles/Weiss_2012_PSS.pdf) (Weiss et al. 2012), the M-type asteroid 21 Lutetia also had a measurable magnetic field.  However,

> whether Lutetia has substantial fine-scale remanent
>   magnetization like that expected from an internal core
>   dynamo (Weiss et al., 2008) or externally generated fields in the
>   early solar system (Weiss et al., 2010).

Additional resources:

> Weiss, B.P., Berdahl, S., Elkins-Tanton, L.T., Stanley, S., Lima, E.A., Carporzen, L.,
>   2008. Magnetism on the angrite parent body and the early differentiation of
>   planetesimals. Science 322, 713–716.
>
> Weiss, B.P., Gattacceca, J., Stanley, S., Rochette, P., Christensen, U.R., 2010.
>   Paleomagnetic records of meteorites and early planetesimal differentiation.
>   Space Science Reviews 152, 341–390.